# Magento admin panel is not loading properly

Tags: admin-panel, migration

We moved the website from one domain to another domain.

but after moving, admin panel is not opening properly.

We changed the domain's secure and unsecure url's in `core_ config_data`.

[image]

Comment: clear the var/cache folder

Comment: deleted, but still same error....

Comment: i think you need to add slash in based url. Like http://youdomain.com/magentoinstall/

Comment: @Raks please delete the site name from your comment

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 so it works for you. Happy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your **base link location** in `System > configuration > Web` from

`http://sitename.in/foldername/var/www/html/folder`

to

```
http://sitename.in/foldernamevar/www/html/folder/
```

note the `/` at the end

Clear your cache and see again

Answer (score 2):

You should check the network tab (or simply have a look at the markup) from where the CSS files are (not) loaded.

One possible explanation is you accessing the login page via HTTPS while CSS files are served via HTTP.

Comment: how to change the access from https to http?

Comment: Did you just ask me how to type a URL into the browser's address bar?

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved using the Database Table `core_ config_data`.

Please update the following 3 Column :
`core_ config_data`.

Find these urls and update

1. (24, 'default', 0, 'web/unsecure/base_skin_url', 'yourdomainURL/skin/'),
2. (25, 'default', 0, 'web/unsecure/base_media_url', 'yourdomainURL/media/'),
3. (26, 'default', 0, 'web/unsecure/base_js_url', 'yourdomainURL/js/').

Once you updated the correct url's, the website will work all fine.